# Hibernate annotation issues

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a problem with my entity class on my springboot application.Below is the error message from the console
`Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.stap.entities.User`
My entity class user looks as follows

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer ID;

    private String name;

    private String email;


    public Integer getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(Integer iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: First thought is to write `id` in lowercase.

Comment: Which Id is imported in your class it is `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` or `javax.persistence.Id` ? Please add the import part of the code.

Comment: @AmitBera I have used import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

Comment: @DENNISKITHINJI You should use `javax.persistence.Id` instead of org.springframework.data.annotation.Id.

Comment: Check if you imported javax.persistence.Id

Comment: Post your `application.properties` and user class with import